# When Using Dynamic Routes in NextJS, bad routes return status 200

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm running the example in the NextJS Repo for dynamic routes that is at this URL:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/dynamic-routing

When running the app and I browse to the URL:

http://localhost:3000/about

It works correctly and displays a good page with a status 200.

When I browse to http://localhost:3000/aboutBADROUTE

I get a 404 as I would expect.

However, this is the current correct route:

http://localhost:3000/post/first (returns 200)

But, this:  http://localhost:3000/post/firstBADROUTE

also returns a 200 which is not what I want. I want that also to return a 404.

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is dynamic route segment (https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction#dynamic-route-segments)

When you visit `/about` it returns 200 because you have `/pages/about.js`

When you visit `/aboutBADROUTE`, it returns 404 because you don't have any pages match that route.

When you visit `/post/first` or `/post/firstBADROUTE`, it will match this:

`post/:id` (so `first` or `firstBADROUTE` is still considered as `id`)

so it will always return 200 when you visit `/post/whatevervalue`.

In your case you can check if it is valid `id` you can show normal page, if it is invalid `id`, you can show error page (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#reusing-the-built-in-error-page)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to include notFound in the result.  This requires some work in getStaticProps, but often I can see that work necessary.

Here is a link to the discussion about it.  That's the answer I was looking for.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10960#discussioncomment-116705